# Edit the spacing between lines in any of Delphi FMX text components

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

is there a way to alter the spacing of any Delphi FMX component ? all are doubled spaced between lines i believe, i'm sure there is a way to edit the spacing between lines. the most important that it work for FMX

[image: Right image Delpih[Memo], Left : Notpad]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly what you are asking and why. Please show some example of *all are doubled spaced between lines I believe* and be more precise with what components you are talking about. What adjustment range would you like to use?

Comment: check update @TomBrunberg

Comment: If you mean the difference between left and right pictures, that's only due to different font size. Just select a font family and a size that gives you the best result, it might require some testing. There's no "double spacing between lines"

Comment: @TomBrunberg: A difference in font size alone wouldn't change the ASCII art's aspect ratio that much. The main difference is that the left image has a monospaced font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two screenshots isn't that they have different line heights or line spacings.

The difference is that the left application is using a *variable-width* font, while the right application is using a [*fixed-width* (monospaced)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) font.

You can see this extremely clearly in the top centre part of the image, where you have four full stops (`....`).

I assume you consider the right screenshot to display the desired appearance. If so, the solution is to change the font in the left application to a fixed-width (monospaced) font.